# telethon ошибка отправки сообщения, как пофиксить?

Tags: python, telethon

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xoheveras\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\client\updates.py", line 570, in _dispatch_update
    await callback(event)
  File "C:\OSPanel\domains\projects\ClonerTG soft\main.py", line 178, in handle_new_message
    await temp_client.send_message(InputPeerChat(int(copyChat_[3])), event.message)
  File "C:\Users\xoheveras\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\client\messages.py", line 903, in send_message
    result = await self(request)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xoheveras\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 30, in __call__
    return await self._call(self._sender, request, ordered=ordered)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xoheveras\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 87, in _call
    result = await future
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.PeerIdInvalidError: An invalid Peer was used. Make sure to pass the right peer type and that the value is valid (for instance, bots cannot start conversations) (caused by SendMessageRequest)
```

Код:

```
# Получаем информацию о вашем аккаунте
me = await temp_client.get_me()

# Получаем список чатов, в которых вы являетесь участником
chats = await temp_client.get_dialogs()

if not any(chat.id == copyChat_[3] for chat in chats):

    await check_and_join_channel_custom(temp_client, copyChat_[4])
    print(f"[Делаю задержку на присоединение для главного скрипта - 15 сек]")
    await getImg_and_set_profile(temp_client, event.from_id.user_id)
    await set_profile_name(temp_client, name)
    await temp_client.send_message(InputPeerChat(int(copyChat_[3])), event.message)
    await asyncio.sleep(15)
else:
    await temp_client.send_message(InputPeerChat(int(copyChat_[3])), event.message) <--- все время тут кидает ошибку, хотя этот скрипт без изменений работал пару минут назад нормально
```

Перерыл все, в доке про это ничего нет

Comment: нельзя писать пользователям по ID, с которыми у тебя нет открытого/начатого диалога

Comment: @ZxNuClear Я перед отправкой вступаю в чат, у меня пользователь вступает в чат а потом пытается отправить